# iPhone:Play .asf streaming audio file on iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to play a streaming audio from a link where i get .asf file. But my program is unable to play it.
I found the below link, where they are talking about the samething..
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/31117-asf-streaming-iphone.html
Seems like, some apps are able to play it. I got confused now.

Could someone guide me whether it is possible to play *.asf file or not on iPhone, if yes, how can i achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have u found a consolidate solution for that so far?

Answer (score 1):

To stream to the iPhone, you will need to implement the standards that Apple has set forth to do [HTTP adaptive streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). They have created a spec that works well with the changing network conditions that surround the iPhone. The key is the segment files that split up your stream into multiple qualities to give that adaptive experience.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But i am not still getting what should i do? Can you please be explain more details?

Comment: Basically the iPhone cannot handle a .ASF stream. It is only designed to work with HTTP streams that fit the exact specs that Apple gives in the link posted above. If you are doing the encoding of the .ASF stream, you will need to change it or publish a 2nd stream that fits the iPhone spec. hope this helps!