# How to play .asf file yon iPhone?

Tags: iphone, streaming, audio-streaming, internet-radio, asf

Any one know how to play .asf file on iPhone as iphone doesn't support asf file which I need to play for Radio streaming. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone:Play .asf streaming audio file on iPhone programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485218/iphoneplay-asf-streaming-audio-file-on-iphone-programmatically)

Comment: Did you ever suss out the problem? I'm in the process of doing just this, but I have a problem reading the Codec ASF/WMA header causing glitches when I call av_decode with FFMPEG

Comment: I am able to get the WMA and ASF file in mp3 format using MMS & FFMPEG libraries. But I am just able to store the track locally. Not able to play the audio continuously. If you sort this problem then I can give you more reference to play this format.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find some code/library that you can use on the iPhone to decode ASF audio.

You may find that you'll have to port the code or library to even get it to work on the iPhone.

Comment: You are right. I have to add some library. But can you help me to find that library. I am really thankful for that.